# I want to send data to controller with ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot

ajax

```
console.log(count);//10
console.log(pno);//4

var form = {
        count:count,
    pno:pno
}
            
$.ajax({
    url: 'product/basket/change',
    type: 'POST',
    data:form
});
```

spring boot controller

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/product/basket/change")
public void basketChange(@RequestParam(name = "form") Map<String, String> data ....){
    ....
}
```

This is my js and Controller code. How can I do send 'count' and 'pno' to Controller?
I try to solve it with goolgle and gpt for 30 mins, but fail..

Comment: Looks like a decent start. Your URL, HTTP method and request body seem to match between client & server. Now, if you want us to help, tell us what the actual problem is: When you execute this code, what goes wrong? Any errors?

Comment: jquery.min.js:2     POST http://localhost:8080/product/product/basket/change 404
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
count @ basket.js:35
onclick @ basket:88
/////////////
The above error is displayed on the network console. I don't see any other errors

Comment: OK, there's a big hint in the URL in the error message. Can you spot it?

Comment: oh sorry , This error was on the front. I made a mistake when copying.////////

XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/product/product/basket/chan

Comment: what if you remove a single "/product" from your url?

Comment: you mean change url to '/basket/change' both? same error..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you send the parameters uncorrectly:
If you want to use this AJAX:

```
var form = {
    count: count,
    pno: pno
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'product/basket/change',
    type: 'POST',
    data: form, // Pass the form object as data
    success: function(response) {
        // Handle the success response
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // Handle the error response
    }
});
```

You should change your Controller, because you are sending the value on the data, so it expected receive it as **@RequestBody** not **@RequestParam**

```
@ResponseBody
@PostMapping("/product/basket/change")
public void basketChange(@RequestBody Map<String, String> data) {
    String count = data.get("count");
    String pno = data.get("pno");
    // Use the count and pno values as needed
    // ...
}
```